# How many shops accepted BTC? Is it somewhere roughly statistics data?

Tags: raw-data

I am writing bachelor thesis. I need to include a graph on "how many shops or companies accepted BTC". Do you know where I can find historic data or a graph for this?

Answer (score 1):

For example you can look at [this](https://spendbitcoins.nl/places/) site. It has a lot of shops who accept bitcoin, but I don't know if it's complete up to date. It does not have a graph, but you have some rough data (498 pages with 10 companies per page, so ~5000 companies)

Comment: coinmap.org is another one

Comment: It's not solution, because I need historical data. I could't do graph with these data...

Comment: Ahh, I didnt know you wanted historical data. That wasnt clear from your question. Im leaving the answer anyway, because it is an answer to the question in the title. I dont know another site or place which has this kind of data, but maybe you can email the two sites, and ask if they have the data. Its a long shot, but maybe worth it